# How to set in Jenkins a credential id for Perforce SCM before starting the job in a slave node?

Tags: jenkins, version-control, perforce

Let me explain what I have before exposing my question. I have a Jenkins with a seed project that creates jobs from groovy scripts using the Job DSL plugin.

I have a job that uses Perforce as SCM. This has been setup from the groovy and the Perforce credentials have been also set using the id passed to credential() inside scm{perforce{credential("perforce1")}}

This job is configured for running only in my slave nodes. 
What I want to do is: I would like the slave node, before the SCM step, sets the credentials for Perforce based in something like environment variable (ex: NODE_SCM) so when launch the build process, the node would set the credentials for using it before the Perforce SCM starts the process.

The credentials for Perforce is now in Jenkins but could be created in runtime or something like that if it is possible what I want to do.

Example: Imagine I have two credentials stored in my Jenkins (perforce1 and perforce2). The variable NODE_SCM would be one of those ids and set it for building the job in the slave node.
I don´t know if I explain correctly what I want to achieve.

Thanks for your attention in advance.

Best regards

Comment: Have you tried using a p4config file at the root level of each job? https://www.perforce.com/manuals/v15.2/cmdref/P4CONFIG.html